# WPF ICommand initialization performance consideration

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, optimization

I am trying to improve the performance of a large WPF application I am working on. In the codebase, I noticed two different instantiations for RelayCommand and was wondering if one is better than the other. The two look something like this:

```
// Option 1

public ICommand MyCommand { get; private set; }

public MyClass()
{
    MyCommand = new RelayCommand(() => 
    {
        // Do something here
    });
}
```

```
// Option 2

private ICommand _myCommand

public ICommand MyCommand => _myCommand ?? (_myCommand = new RelayCommand(() => /* Do something here */ ));
```

I have always initialized my command in the constructor, but I am interested in whether or not the second option is more efficient in some cases. From my understanding, option 2 seems to create a new instance of `RelayCommand` every time it's requested which is bad in terms of memory usage. But what if I were to combine the two approaches:

```
private ICommand _myCommand;

public ICommand MyCommand => _myCommand ??= new RelayCommand((_) => /* Do something here */ );
```

Is there any performance benefit to choosing one over the other or is this just syntactic sugar? Is my solution any better than the two options mentioned above?

Comment: Option 2 does a null check, so the command is only created once. If the command is never used the option 2 will save a few clock ticks, otherwise they are pretty equal in time. Definitely premature optimisation.

Comment: I think your second one is just a mistake. It should be `public ICommand MyCommand => _myCommand ?? (_myCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ... ));`. It is old way before introduction of `??=` and exactly same as third one.

Comment: There is a difference. Whether it is significant or not delends on what creating the icommand does exactly. Creating in the constructor means the processing occurs on instantiation. The other option ( if you fix it)  means the processing occurs when the command is first used. The difference might be negligible.

Comment: @emoacht That is what I meant to write. I fixed it. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @Andy In my case, I have at least 100 of these `RelayCommand` objects, most of which are rarely used. I know that `RelayCommand` is not a very heavy object but in an application that requires a lot of resources every bit of performance I can squeeze out of it matters. Thanks for your input!

Comment: It's the equivalent of a getter.

Comment: And if it was an initializer, when would the backing field ever be null?

Comment: This is certainly not where your performance bottleneck is. Your first option is slightly better than the other two as you don't have to check whether the field has been initialized though.

Comment: The implementation of `RelayCommand` is important here. If it captures a `SynchronizationContext`, these two options are not equivalent.